# Handling state value in If condition in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I've started using Semantic UI a few days ago and I've come accross an issue recently to which I have not yet found an answer. How do you handle the state value of class within an if condition?

What I am trying to do here is make a side menu that will display only when the user clicks on a button and hides when the user clicks outside of the displayed menu. Something like Semantic's sidebar but without the whole .pusher component.

So basically I need an if condition that checks the "visible" state value, and if it is equal to 'none' change it to 'block' (enable display) or vice versa. 
So far I coded this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Input, Label, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export class SidebarMenuEX extends Component {

constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state = {activeItem: 'inbox', visible: 'none'};
}

handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

handleDisplay(){
if {this.state[visible]} = 'none'
this.setState({visible = 'block'})
}

render() {
const { activeItem } = this.state.activeItem
const { visible } = this.state.visible

return (
  <Menu vertical display = 'none'>
    <Menu.Item name='inbox' active={activeItem === 'inbox'} onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
      <Label color='teal'>1</Label>
      Inbox
    </Menu.Item>

    <Menu.Item name='spam' active={activeItem === 'spam'} onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
      <Label>51</Label>
      Spam
    </Menu.Item>

    <Menu.Item name='updates' active={activeItem === 'updates'} onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
      <Label>1</Label>
      Updates
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>
      <Input icon='search' placeholder='Search mail...' />
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
)
}
```

Obviously my handleDisplay() method does not work but I'd like to understand why the If condition does not recognise `this.state.visible` or `this.state[visible]` as valid (it says [js] ':' expected). Does anyone know a work-around this problem? Thanks!

D.

Comment: `if { ... }` is not valid JavaScript, but `if ( ... )` is.

Comment: Indeed, but I still get an error on the if condition: if (this.state.visible) = 'none'. The equal sign is not recognized as a valid expression

Comment: try `if (this.state.visible === 'none')` you are using assign instead of comparing

Comment: try `if (this.state.visible === 'none') {this.setState({visible: 'block'})}`

Comment: Again, that is not valid JavaScript. You'd want something like `(this.state.visible === 'none')`. I really don't know what can be done to this question if the main issues are syntactical.

Comment: That did the trick! Sorry for the disturbance, I'm still getting used to react js coding. Thanks for all the constructive feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer with the valid JS syntax is:

```
if (this.state.visible === 'none') {
  this.setState({visible: 'block'});
}
```